# How to synchronize QNetworkAccessManager?

Tags: c++, qt, asynchronous, synchronization

My  `deleteIdList` variable is coming from `replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)` function. But `deleteIdList` variable returning empty. However, it have to return anything..I want to synchronize `QNetworkAccessManager`..

```
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

    foreach (QString delIdList, deleteIdList) {

    serviceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/limit_id="+delIdList+"&false";
    requestUrl = QString("%1%2:%3%4").arg(scheme).arg(qstr).arg(QString::number(svcPort)).arg(serviceUrl);

    QUrl url(requestUrl);
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(url);
    manager->get(request);

  }
```

How to synchronize QNetworkAccessManager ?

Answer (score 1):

I might be late, but I think it could help others facing this issue.

```
QNetworkAccessManager *networkMgr = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QNetworkReply *reply = networkMgr->get( QNetworkRequest( QUrl( "http://www.google.com" ) ) );

QEventLoop loop;
QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));

// Execute the event loop here, now we will wait here until readyRead() signal is emitted
// which in turn will trigger event loop quit.
loop.exec();

// Lets print the HTTP GET response.
qDebug( reply->readAll());
```

[Source : developer.nokia.com](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_wait_synchronously_for_a_Signal_in_Qt)

Answer (score 0):

Erm... what are you doing? You create a QNetWorkManager, connect the finished signal to a replyFinished slot and expect to get a result, which comes from replyFinished before you even sent the request? Sorry, but from what I see in your code, I'd say it is beyond repair.

The `foreach (QString delIdList, deleteIdList)` must be in the replyFinished slot, when deleteIdList is somehow a result of your request. And

```
    QUrl url(requestUrl);
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(url);
    manager->get(request);
```

must be outside the loop below your connect. But of course, your code is so wrong, that my 'hints' are just rough guess work about what you **might** intend to do.

Comment: I am doing it: There is `deleteIdList`  in the `replyFinished` function ..  And this function must return `deleteIdList`..After that I want to use this variable.. each element of `QStringList deleteIdList` is my ID value. So, Each ID seperately must be request with manager->get(request)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to understand the question -- but I have some advice none-the-less which is: never use the finished signal of QNetworkAccessManager. Instead connect to the finished slot of QNetworkReply.

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

foreach (QString delIdList, deleteIdList) {

    serviceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/limit_id="+delIdList+"&false";
    requestUrl = QString("%1%2:%3%4").arg(scheme).arg(qstr).arg(QString::number(svcPort)).arg(serviceUrl);

    QUrl url(requestUrl);
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(url);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
    connect(reply,SIGNAL(finished()),this,SLOT(replyFinished()));
}
```

Then in the replyFinished slot you can call sender() to receive a pointer to the reply. In this way, you can "synchronize" and figure out which reply belongs to which request.

Comment: I don't see how this can help him. According to him:  
**My deleteIdList variable is coming from replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)**. So how is this 'deleteIdList' fed back into his foreach loop from the replyFinished() slot? I think we can point to mistakes, but we don't have enough information how it could be done correctly.

Comment: Agreed. The question is confusing and I'm not sure what he's asking. This is only a suggestion based on one possible interpretation of a question that is perhaps not written by a native English speaker.

Comment: I want to wait reply `replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)` function.. :/